# How to create Numpy matrix of row index where a certain condition is met?

Tags: numpy, matrix, where-clause

How do I convert a numpy matrix of values to numpy matrix of row indexes where a certain condition is met?

Let's say

```
A = array([[ 0.,  5.,  0.],[ 0.,  0.,  3.],[ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

If there is a condition that I want to use here -- if an element is greater than 0 then replace it by row index+1, how would I do it?
So output should be,

```
B = array([[0., 1., 0.],[0., 0., 2.],[0., 0., 0.]])
```

Not sure if I am using np.where correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `numpy.where`

```
np.where(A>0, np.arange(1, A.shape[0]+1)[:, None], A)
```

```
array([[0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

---

Or you can use arithmetic (won't work if you have values *less* than `0`):

```
(A > 0) * np.arange(1, A.shape[0]+1)[:, None]
```

Comment: Thanks - this works! Just a quick follow-up question -- can the first condition be anything? Like if we want to keep just the max of each column, (np.max(A, axis=0) ??) and everything else is 0? So if A[0,2] = 1 instead, can B[0,2] just be 0 instead of 1?